# Convert byte stream to byte array without extra space

Tags: java, arrays, memory, stream

I have a ByteArrayOutputStream that has large amounts of data written into, which is ultimately converted into a byte array and written to a cache:

```
try {
      ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      try (JsonGenerator jg = mapper.getFactory().createGenerator(baos)) {
        for (Object result : results) {
          jg.writeObject(result);
        }
      }

      localCache.put(cacheKey, baos.toByteArray());
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      throw Throwables.propagate(e);
    }
```

Here `baos.toByteArray()` creates a whole new copy of the data in memory, which I'm trying to avoid. Is there a way to convert the stream to a byte array without using the extra memory?

Comment: I think you need the additional space. Either you let BAOS create a copy and give it you or you hold a reference to the byte array in BAOS. However, the second option might result in 'memory leak' as BAOS object constructed will never get destroyed. Could you put the BAOS constructed in the localCache?

Comment: unfortunately the localcache only accepts array of bytes.

Answer (score 2):

The internal buffer and current count are `protected` fields documented in the Javadoc.  This means you should be OK to subclass `ByteArrayOutputStream` and provide a `byte[] getBuffer()` method to access the buffer directly. Use the existing `size()` method to determine how much data is present.

```
public class MyBAOS extends ByteArrayOutputStream
{
    public MyBAOS()           { super(); }
    public MyBAOS(int size)   { super(size); }
    public byte[] getBuffer() { return buf; }
}
```